# How to make input fields in the gift message required on the checkout page in Magento 1.8?

Tags: magento-1.8, checkout, onepage-checkout, onestepcheckout

How can I make the input fields in the gift message compulsory/ required on the checkout page?

By Magento's default, you don't have to fill in these fields below, but I need to make it required if the checkbox of `id="allow_gift_messages_for_order"` is checked.

```
To
From
Message
```

This is the code,

```
<div class="allow-gift-messages-for-order-container" id="allow-gift-messages-for-order-container" style="display:none">
    <p class="micro-text-cart"><?php echo $this->__('You can leave this box blank if you do not wish to add a gift message for whole order.') ?></p>
    <input type="hidden" name="giftmessage[<?php echo $this->getEntity()->getId() ?>][type]"  value="quote" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <ul>
            <li class="fields">

                <div class="form-group col-lg-6 field control-group name-lastname">
                    <label for="gift-message-whole-from"><?php echo $this->__('From') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" name="giftmessage[<?php echo $this->getEntity()->getId() ?>][from]" id="gift-message-whole-from" title="<?php echo $this->__('From') ?>"  value="<?php echo $this->getEscaped($this->getMessage()->getSender(), $this->getDefaultFrom()) ?>" class="input-text validation-passed form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-lg-6 field control-group">
                    <label for="gift-message-whole-to"><?php echo $this->__('To') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" name="giftmessage[<?php echo $this->getEntity()->getId() ?>][to]" id="gift-message-whole-to" title="<?php echo $this->__('To') ?>" value="<?php echo $this->getEscaped($this->getMessage()->getRecipient(), $this->getDefaultTo()) ?>" class="input-text validation-passed form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>

            </li>
            <li class="wide">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="gift-message-whole-message"><?php echo $this->__('Message') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <textarea id="gift-message-whole-message" onchange="toogleRequired('gift-message-whole-message', ['gift-message-whole-from','gift-message-whole-to'])" class="input-text validation-passed giftmessage-area form-control" name="giftmessage[<?php echo $this->getEntity()->getId() ?>][message]" title="<?php echo $this->__('Message') ?>" rows="5" cols="10"><?php echo $this->getEscaped($this->getMessage()->getMessage()) ?></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        toogleRequired('gift-message-whole-message', ['gift-message-whole-from','gift-message-whole-to']);
    //]]>
    </script>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

```
<form name="my-custom-form" id="my-custom-form" action="" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
    <ul>
        <li class="fields">

            <div class="form-group col-lg-6 field control-group name-lastname">
                <label for="gift-message-whole-from" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('From') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" name="giftmessage[<?php echo $this->getEntity()->getId() ?>][from]" id="gift-message-whole-from" title="<?php echo $this->__('From') ?>"  value="<?php echo $this->getEscaped($this->getMessage()->getSender(), $this->getDefaultFrom()) ?>" class="input-text required-entry form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-lg-6 field control-group">
                <label for="gift-message-whole-to" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('To') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" name="giftmessage[<?php echo $this->getEntity()->getId() ?>][to]" id="gift-message-whole-to" title="<?php echo $this->__('To') ?>" value="<?php echo $this->getEscaped($this->getMessage()->getRecipient(), $this->getDefaultTo()) ?>" class="input-text required-entry form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>

        </li>
        <li class="wide">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="gift-message-whole-message"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Message') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <textarea id="gift-message-whole-message" onchange="toogleRequired('gift-message-whole-message', ['gift-message-whole-from','gift-message-whole-to'])" class="input-text required-entry giftmessage-area form-control" name="giftmessage[<?php echo $this->getEntity()->getId() ?>][message]" title="<?php echo $this->__('Message') ?>" rows="5" cols="10"><?php echo $this->getEscaped($this->getMessage()->getMessage()) ?></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    toogleRequired('gift-message-whole-message', ['gift-message-whole-from','gift-message-whole-to']);
//]]>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //< ![CDATA[
        var customForm = new VarienForm('my-custom-form');
    //]]>
</script>
```

**EDIT:**

I got it solved! Need to edit the checkout.js in IWD OPC extension actually,

```
....
....

initSaveOrder: function(){

            $j(document).on('click', '.opc-btn-checkout', function(){
                if (IWD.OPC.Checkout.disabledSave==true){
                    return;
                }
                var addressForm = new VarienForm('billing-new-address-form');
                if (!addressForm.validator.validate()){             
                    return;
                }

                console.log($j('input[name="allow_gift_messages_for_order"]').prop('checked'));
                if ($j('input[name="allow_gift_messages_for_order"]').prop('checked') === true){
                    var giftForm = new VarienForm('gift-message-form');
                    if (!giftForm.validator.validate()){                
                        return;
                    }
                }

                if (!$j('input[name="billing[use_for_shipping]"]').prop('checked')){
                    var addressForm = new VarienForm('opc-address-form-shipping');
                    if (!addressForm.validator.validate()){             
                        return;
                    }
                }

                IWD.OPC.saveOrderStatus = true;
                IWD.OPC.Plugin.dispatch('saveOrderBefore');
                if (IWD.OPC.Checkout.isVirtual===false){
                    IWD.OPC.Shipping.saveShippingMethod();
                }else{
                    IWD.OPC.validatePayment();
                }
            });

    },
  ...
  ...
```

inline.html,

```
<div class="form-group" id="gift-message-form">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="fields">

                                <div class="form-group col-lg-6 field control-group name-lastname">
                                    <label for="gift-message-whole-from" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('From') ?></label>
                                    <div class="input-box">
                                        <input type="text" name="giftmessage[<?php echo $this->getEntity()->getId() ?>][from]" id="gift-message-whole-from" title="<?php echo $this->__('From') ?>"  value="<?php echo $this->getEscaped($this->getMessage()->getSender(), $this->getDefaultFrom()) ?>" class="input-text required-entry form-control" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group col-lg-6 field control-group">
                                    <label for="gift-message-whole-to" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('To') ?></label>
                                    <div class="input-box">
                                        <input type="text" name="giftmessage[<?php echo $this->getEntity()->getId() ?>][to]" id="gift-message-whole-to" title="<?php echo $this->__('To') ?>" value="<?php echo $this->getEscaped($this->getMessage()->getRecipient(), $this->getDefaultTo()) ?>" class="input-text required-entry form-control" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </li>
                            <li class="wide">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="gift-message-whole-message" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Message') ?></label>
                                    <div class="input-box">
                                        <textarea id="gift-message-whole-message" onchange="toogleRequired('gift-message-whole-message', ['gift-message-whole-from','gift-message-whole-to'])" class="input-text required-entry giftmessage-area form-control" name="giftmessage[<?php echo $this->getEntity()->getId() ?>][message]" title="<?php echo $this->__('Message') ?>" rows="5" cols="10"><?php echo $this->getEscaped($this->getMessage()->getMessage()) ?></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

Comment: i cant able to see form tag above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form action="" method="post" id="someid">
<input type="checkbox" class="required-entry" />
<div class="actions">
                <button type="submit" title="Subscribe" class="button"><span><span>Sign Up</span></span></button>
            </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var FormDetail = new VarienForm('someid');
    //]]>
    </script>
```

i have gave you sample code in sample format.
for validation to work.it should have a form and some id to it.
and last it should have the script tag as shown in the code

Comment: I added that but it does not validate the form at all...

Comment: wat code you aded can you share

Comment: can you take a look on my edit above please. thanks.

Comment: worked for you ?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add a "required-entry" class to your inputs and Magento will magecly add front-end != empty validation.

A little more on the subject from Inchoo: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/out-of-the-box-form-validation-in-magento/

Comment: I added "required-entry" to the input fields but not working.... :(

Comment: you cleared cache after editing? no apc running?

Comment: Oh it is an opc extension running on my checkout page. is it something to do with it?